# Не регистрируется приложение в instagram

Tags: веб-программирование, instagram

Здравствуйте!

Пытаюсь зарегистрировать сайт в качестве приложения в инстаграме, чтобы выводить на нём фотографии из аккаунта. Но по непонятной причине не проходит регистрация... Хотя делаю всё, как мне кажется, по инструкции, но получается вот такая ерунда
[image: регистрация приложения в инстаграме]

Быть может кто-то сталкивался с проблемой? Как исправить проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Не тратьте время в пустую, используйте Private API. Политика Instagram в настоящее время предполагает обязательное review всех приложений для доступа к их Public API (до этого они находятся в режиме "песочницы"). С той целью, с которой вы регистрируете приложение Instagram не выдает даже базовых permission.

Comment: Что-то ничего толкового не нагуглил на тему Private API. Можете дать ссылку на какой-нибудь материал?

Comment: это там и нет, смотрите готовый код на github